# Exception While Connecting to mysql db with play framework

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

I am working with PlayFramework (2.3.x) application. I wanted to connect to a mysql db. Below is the configuration that I had given in `application.conf`:

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
db.default.username=root
db.default.password=root
db.default.logStatements=true
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnitName
```

When I run the application I am getting the following exception

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:247)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onStart(DB.scala:238)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:253)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:289)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:284)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:284)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1665)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1207)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:240)
    ... 18 more
```

1. I have my db created and I am able to use with mysql console.
2. I have my persistence.xml placed in my conf/META-INF. Below is the persistence.xml
3. I have root user with all privileges.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs for Play 2.3.x](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaDatabase#MySQL-database-engine-connection-properties), the correct configuration is `db.default.user` and not `db.default.username`. That is probably the cause of the exception. So change your configuration to:

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=root
db.default.logStatements=true
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnitName
```

Comment: yup. I noticed and corrected it. Its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a login, as indicated by the line

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: db.default.username=root
db.default.password=root                                                                                 DB credentials are present in config .